# How to copy or select content between brackets or opening to closing html with Atom (Including the tags themselves)?

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom you can use `[ctrl + m]` to goto the matching bracket or closing html tag.

How can you select the content from the beginning of / including the opening bracket / html to the end of/including closing bracket or closing tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emmet has keybindings that expand/reduce selections to a tag which they call "balance outward/inward":

- Balance (outward): `ctrl-shift-E`
- Balance (inward): `ctrl-shift-0`

Emmet for Atom docs: https://atom.io/packages/emmet

Comment: Nice that works well. Emmet comes packages with vscode so you can [create custom keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) for the balances.

Answer (score 4):

To select all the text inside the current brackets or opening to closing html with Atom

- For Mac OS X `[ctrl-cmd-m]`
- For Windows `[ctrl-alt-m]`

Comment: Is there a shrortcut that includes the enclosing html element / outer element?

Comment: To select all enclosing content inside an html tag. Go to that tag (opening/closing) and use above mentioned short-cut. It will select all content inside that tag but it will not include that tag.

Comment: Hope so this answer fulfils your question for 50reputation :)

Comment: Just clarified the question a bit, with what I said in the comment. Your attempt was close, but not quite the expected result. Bounty stands for 3 days.

Comment: Consider deleting this answer, the question is asking how to select "including the opening bracket". Peace.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that the key sequence to select text in between brackets has probably changed from version to version.  In Atom 1.58.0 for Windows (the one I am using) the key sequence to select text is ctrl-alt, .  Yes, that's right control alt comma.

In any event, whatever version you have, you should be able to find the key sequence in the Settings for the package shown in Atom.  Go to Packages > Installed Packages.  Enter "bracket-matcher" in the search field.  When the bracket-matcher package comes up click on the Settings button.  In the Settings there is a section called Keybindings.  There you will find the key sequence that works for your Atom installation.